# How do I make a script to launch a program from the folder of a usb?

Tags: html, google-chrome, scripting, directory, usb

My task is to plug my usb into one of our computers, run a script, and then it run a program through google chrome. I have done this successfully, the only issue is that almost every computer I plug my usb into reads the usb in a different directory i.e. F: D: E: C: G: and so on.

I need a way to streamline this instead of having 7 different scripts to choose from... Here is my script as it stands now=

---

@echo off

cd "F:\skywardaccess.htm"
start chrome F:\skywardaccess.htm

exit

---

Thank you for your help and advice :)

Comment: the thing I am trying to change is "F:\skywardaccess.htm" so that it boots from whatever directory it is in.

Comment: and the script is running from the usb, correct?

Comment: yes it is running from the usb

Comment: And the htm file is on the usb too? And this is Windows?

Comment: the htm is on the usb and this is windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your problem is only that you're overthinking it. Anytime a batch is ran, its working directory is automatically set to where it's being run from. So, if your script is in the same folder as what ever you want to run, all you need to do is

```
@echo off
skywardaccess.htm
exit
```

The only difference being that, unless the .htm extension has already had a default browser set, it will ask you what browser you want to open it with.

Side note; since it's only opening a file, `@echo off` and `exit` are both unnecessary.  You could have your batch just say `filename.extension` and it will run.

**EDIT**

As previously explained, no change of directory is needed. You can try;

```
start chrome.exe test.htm
```

but this only works if their chrome is on an indexed location, such as C:/ but this cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: i need my script to specify chrome because it will otherwise launch in microsoft edge, chrome is my preffered browser, so do i change it to this?:

Comment: cd "skywardaccess.htm" start chrome skywardaccess.htm